# How do you get the details of the currently selected file/folder in a Swift app on macOS?

Tags: swift, macos, finder

I am working on a Swift app for Mac Desktop. My application depends on what file or folder the user has selected in the Finder window. But I don't see any events in FileSystem API or NSWorkspace Shared API to get these details.

Flow of App

- My application is running in the background
- User opens Finder and selects any file or folder
- My app will show the file name or folder name

Please advise or guide in a direction.

I have looked at File System Events, fswatcher, and NSShared Workspace related APIs so far.

Comment: You would need to ask the Finder application, for example via NSAppleScript.

Comment: Not sure this is possible due to restrictions in system. The access to a file is ultimately done by the underlying Unix file system which is the only to know when a file is open or a directory is read. In unix you have the lsof command which can gives you this kind of info (I think monitor app use this)

Answer (score 0):

> … currently selected file/folder in a Swift app on macOS?

Since `FileManager` and `NSWorkspace` have not provided for the current macOS Finder selection, I created (and have been using for several years) a package which wraps some AppleScript with a Swift API via the Apple [Open Scripting Architecture (OSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript#Open_Scripting_Architecture).

**Example Use:**

```swift
import OSAxFinderLib

internal let osaxFinder = OSAxFinder()

let extensions = ["jpg", "png"]
let imageUrls = osaxFinder.selectedFileUrls(extensions: extensions)
for url in imageUrls {
  // …
}
```

**Implemented Scripts:**

```applescript
on finderFrontWindow()
    tell application "Finder"
        set theWin to window 1
        set thePath to (POSIX path of (target of theWin as alias))
    end tell
    return thePath
end finderFrontWindow
```

```applescript
on finderSelection()
    tell application "Finder"
        set these_items to the selection as alias list
    end tell
    
    set posixList to {}
    repeat with i from 1 to the count of these_items
        set this_item to (item i of these_items) as alias
        
        -- --- log file information --- 
        -- set this_info to info for this_item
        -- log this_info
        
        -- file list
        set posixForm to (POSIX path of this_item)
        set end of posixList to (posixForm & "\n")
    end repeat
    return posixList as string
end finderSelection
```

**Details:**

See GitHub repository: [OSAxFinderLib](https://github.com/marc-medley/OSAxFinderLib)